# Edit an entity contains an file field

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have created an entity `Article`, with a field image. Eveything is working fine, but when I try to update and edit an article, I got the oldest fields like `titre` but not the image field. I got an empty image and I have to upload a new image. I want to get the oldest picture, btw, I have the path of the picture stored on the db.

This is my form **`ArticleType.php`**

```
<?php
namespace RoubBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('titre')  
           ->add('image', 'file')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'RoubBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }
}
```

This is my entity **`article.php`**:

```
<?php

namespace RoubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoubBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez mettre vos images.")
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize="5242880",
     *      mimeTypes = {
     *          "image/png",
     *          "image/jpeg",
     *          "image/jpg",
     *          "image/gif"
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $titre;

    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
 }
```

And this is in my **`ArticleController.php`**:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $article->setImage(
    new File($this->getParameter('images_directory').'/'.$article->getImage()));
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($article);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('RoubBundle\Form\ArticleType',  $article);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_edit', array('id' =>   $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('RoubBundle:article:edit.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

If someone can help me, and thank you a lot for being here, and read my problem until here <3

Answer (score 0):

Keep a clone of your image somewhere at the start of your function, before handling the request :

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Article $article)
{
   $originalImage = clone $article->getImage();
   // .. rest of your function here
```

And when your form is valid, check if you have a new image, if not, set the old one back:

```
if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

  if ($article->getImage()) {
    $article->setImage($originalImage);
  }
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($article);
  $em->flush();

  return $this->redirectToRoute('article_edit', array('id' =>   $article->getId()));
}
```

It's pseudo code, but you get the idea. I'm using `clone` here in case you have a reference to an object, but if it's just a path you can simply assign the value.

---

**EDIT** : Clarify where stuff should go

Comment: that's the same thing, i did it like that, in the ArticleController.php
    
        $article->setImage(
        new File($this->getParameter('images_directory').'/'.$article->getImage()));

Comment: No you didn't. The `$article->setImage()` stuff must be in your `if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {` block. I edited my answer

Comment: i understand sir, thank you very much for you answers :)

Comment: hey tchap, can you take a look for this post and thank you. 
[multi-upload-files-on-symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560014/multi-upload-files-on-symfony2-8)