# Multi upload files on symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.5, multi-upload

i was doing a multi upload files on symfony2.8 and i find always problems, 
and i always got this : 
**"Expected argument of type "string", "array" given"**

this is my entity /Article.php

```
<?php

namespace RoubBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RoubBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * 
 * @Assert\File(
 *      maxSize="5242880",
 *      mimeTypes = {
 *          "image/png",
 *          "image/jpeg",
 *          "image/jpg",
 *          "image/gif"
 *      }
 * )
 */
public $image= array();

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string
 */
private $titre;

public function getTitre()
{
    return $this->titre;
}

public function setTitre($titre)
{
    $this->titre = $titre;

    return $this;
}


public function getImage() {
    return $this->image;
}
public function setImage(array $image) {
    $this->image = $image;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
}
```

and this is my action NewAction in my controller /ArticleController.php

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new Article();
    $form = $this->createForm('RoubBundle\Form\ArticleType', $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if (null !== $article->getImage) {   
    foreach($file as $article->getImage) {    

/** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
        $file = $article->getImage();

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        array_push($article->getImage(), $fileName);
        }
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('RoubBundle:article:new.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

this is form /ArticleType.php

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('titre')    
        ->add('image', 'file', array(
                    'required' => false,
                        'data_class' => null,
                    "multiple" => "multiple"))    
    ;
}
```

and i try this in my twig /new.html.twig

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form.titre) }} </br>                                         
 {{ form_widget(form.image, { 'attr': { 'multiple': 'multiple' } }) }}                            
                             </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

guys, i wish that someone could help me, i am really stressed about it
and thank you.

Comment: http://gullele.com/multiple-file-upload-in-symfony2-example/ you can use this blog

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that $image is of type string in your entity:

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
```

So you need first to figure out how you want to save list of images in your database. The good way to do this would be creating a new table (and Entity) called article_images which looks like this for example:

```
$id
$imageUrl
$articleId
```

If you dont want another table you can try and save your images array as a json. To do this use

```
 @ORM\Column(type="json")
```

on your $image field.

Second problem is your "moving" code. You are pushing values at the end of array, while you only want the "moved" ones. Here is what it could look like:

```
 if ($article->getImage()) {   

    $movedImages = array();

    foreach($article->getImage() as $index=>$file) {    

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('images_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        array_push($movedImages, $fileName);
        }

        $article->setImage($movedImages);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }
```

Comment: thank you for you answer sir, i am an amateur in symfony and when i tryed this  `* @ORM\Column(type="json")`, i got **Unknown column type json request** when i try to update my schema ...

Comment: so i tried `@ORM\Column(type="array")` but still not working and i get **"Expected argument of type "string", "array" given"** @tchap

Comment: @zlot do you have more stacktrace/log of this error? I mean does it say where it occurs?

And please try setting file multiple to true instead of multiple in ArticleType.php. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/file.html#multiple